# Pesquisar post e carregá-lo em uma div usando Ajax no Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Tenho a seguinte estrutura no wordpress.

```
<input type="text" id="busca_artigo">
<button id="btn_busca_artigo">Enviar</button>

<div id="resultado_pesquisa"></div>
<button id="volta_artigo">Anterior</button>
<button id="proximo_artigo">Próximo</button>
```

Quero pesquisar uma palavra e com AJAX carregar o primeiro resultado na div #resultado_pesquisa.

Eu pesquisei nos tutoriais, mas, não os entendi direito, tem alguns que incluem o código todo no functions.php, outros colocam uma parte num arquivo ajax.js.

Não precisa ser uma busca no post todo, pode ser uma pesquisa apenas no título do post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é separar em arquivos não fazer tudo no functions, oque você pede em sua questão é um pouco grande pra colocar aqui mas vou tentar exemplificar bem, primeiramente você deve criar um evento com jquery ou javascript puro para esse input, eu recomendo utilizar o .on("input") (caso utilize jquery).
Dentro desse evento do input você deve fazer uma requisição ajax, para isso você irá necessitar carregar um arquivo do wordpress chamado admin-ajax.php, para isso coloque no functions do seu tema as seguintes linhas de código:

```
    function Wps_load_scripts() {
     wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/javascript.js');
     wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'ajaxLoad_ajaxurl', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') );

      wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script');

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Wps_load_scripts');
```

A função wp_localize_script irá permitir você utilizar este arquivo dentro do seu JS, então ali no "my-script" você coloca o nome do JS que você vai manipular.

Depois de realizado isso você vai fazer o seguinte no arquivo JS :

```
  $content = $(".divquedesejocolocarmeuconteudo");
      $('#meuinput').on('input', function() {
        var title_page , input;
        input = $(this);
        title_page = input.val();

        var datasend = {action: 'load_input_post', title:title_page};
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data: datasend,
          dataType: "json", //Esse retorno pode ser em HTML tbm
          url: ajaxLoad_ajaxurl, /*Isso daqui é a variavel que passamos pelo 
          localize_script dentro do functions*/
          beforeSend: function() {
                 /* geralmente onde se coloca o loader */
          },     
              success: function(data) {
               if(typeof data != "undefined" && typeof data !== null) { 
                 if(typeof data.conteudo1 != "undefined" && typeof data.conteudo1 !== null) {       
                  $content.html(data.conteudo1);
              }
             }
            }else {
                 /* remover loader */
          }
    });
```

A variavel "datasend" passamos 2 valores, action (que é a função que vai ser chamada pelo ajax pro php) e o title que é o titulo pesquisado.

Muito bem, assim que construido isso no seu javascript podemos partir para o functions.php

No functions.php do seu tema você vai criar uma função com o mesmo nome que você colocar no valor da action, ali no datasend (no js).

```
    function load_input_post(){

      $page_title = (isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : '' ); 
      $tipodopost = 'post';
      /* para recuperar a página pelo titulo você pode usar a função get_page_by_title ()*/
      $page = get_page_by_title($pagetitle, OBJECT, $tipodopost);

     /*Pronto, agora a variavel $page armazena todas as informações da página, use como desejar*/
      /* se você for retornar um HTML já construido você deve fazer o seguinte */
      <?php
        ob_start(); 
        $var = "teste";
        $var = "teste2";
      ?> 

      <h1>teste</h1>
      <img src="<?php echo  $var; ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $var_2; ?>">

      <?php 
      $teste = ob_get_clean();
      /* usei o  ob_get_clean() pois é mais rapido, faça o método que desejar */

      /* para enviar o $teste de volta para seu JS para que possa colocar no conteudo retorno um JSON */

       $response = array();
       $response['conteudo1'] = $teste;
       wp_send_json($response); /*enviado de volta para o js */

    }
add_action('wp_ajax_load_input_post', 'load_input_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_input_post', 'load_input_post');

/*Essas duas linhas de cima são necessárias para o wp entender que isto acima é uma função para requisição ajax, os nomes "wp-ajax" e "wp-ajax-nopriv" são prefixos, para em seguida surgir o nome da sua função, o nopriv é para usuários não logados*/
```

HTML exemplo:

```
<input type="text" id="meuinput">

<div class="divquedesejocolocarmeuconteudo"></div>
```

O código acima é o método que costumo usar e funciona kkkk, se tiver alguma alternativa melhor vou ficar acompanhando o post, o código foi pensado num cenário onde você não tem os posts listados e tem que busca-los na base, se o post ja estiver na página, basta fazer um filtragrem pelo js sem precisar do ajax, espero ter ajudado.